# Using Ghoul Army spell as am Oracle with the Tongues curse

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoning, languages

My character just reached Orcale level 10 and I was looking through 5th level spells. I came across the spell [Ghoul Army](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/ghoul-army) but was told by another player that I cannot use it because as an Oracle with the [Tongues Curse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/oracle-curses#TOC-Tongues) I would not be able to command the Ghouls and Ghast since their language is common and I cannot speak that while in battle

I agreed that I could not speak with them, but would they know what to attack or would they just stand next to me the whole time.

Also would it be feasible to use [Share Language Communal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/share-language#TOC-Share-Language-Communal) to speak with them? I understand that it would take an extra turn and spell, but might be worth it just to stick it to the rules lawyering player in my group who believes he is the only who can do anything slightly unique or interesting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many spells that produce minions include text that specifies what the critters do if not specifically commanded otherwise. *Summon Monster I*, for example, says that creatures not otherwise commanded will attack the caster's enemies to the best of their ability. *Ghoul Army* has no such text.

As a result, the ghouls and ghast created by *Ghoul Army* are under no obligation to do anything other than obey your spoken commands. If you don't give your ghouls spoken commands they can understand, they will revert to doing what ghouls usually do when not beholden to someone else, i.e.: snack on any tasty flesh nearby and find a crypt to hide out in. Since your character is likely made of tasty flesh, casting this spell without the ability to speak to them is likely to backfire.

Theoretically, yes, you could use *Share Language Communal* to speak with them. However, note that the spell requires you to touch your targets and allows a will save; The ghouls can (and likely will) resist your casting an unidentified spell on them, especially if they're thinking of eating you.